Getting error with Sharp/Libvips when installing node modules in a next application
yarn install            
yarn install v1.22.22
info No lockfile found.
[1/4]   Resolving packages...
warning eslint > @humanwhocodes/config-array@0.13.0: Use @eslint/config-array instead
warning eslint > @humanwhocodes/config-array > @humanwhocodes/object-schema@2.0.3: Use @eslint/object-schema instead
warning eslint > file-entry-cache > flat-cache > rimraf@3.0.2: Rimraf versions prior to v4 are no longer supported
warning eslint > file-entry-cache > flat-cache > rimraf > glob@7.2.3: Glob versions prior to v9 are no longer supported
warning eslint > file-entry-cache > flat-cache > rimraf > glob > inflight@1.0.6: This module is not supported, and leaks memory. Do not use it. Check out lru-cache if you want a good and tested way to coalesce async requests by a key value, which is much more comprehensive and powerful.
warning node-pre-gyp@0.12.0: Please upgrade to @mapbox/node-pre-gyp: the non-scoped node-pre-gyp package is deprecated and only the @mapbox scoped package will recieve updates in the future
warning node-pre-gyp > rimraf@2.7.1: Rimraf versions prior to v4 are no longer supported
warning node-pre-gyp > rimraf > glob@7.2.3: Glob versions prior to v9 are no longer supported
warning node-pre-gyp > npmlog@4.1.2: This package is no longer supported.
warning node-pre-gyp > nopt > osenv@0.1.5: This package is no longer supported.
warning node-pre-gyp > npmlog > gauge@2.7.4: This package is no longer supported.
warning node-pre-gyp > npmlog > are-we-there-yet@1.1.7: This package is no longer supported.
[2/4]   Fetching packages...
[3/4]   Linking dependencies...
[4/4]   Building fresh packages...
[-/2] ⡀ waiting...
error /Users/thedreamsaver/Downloads/DevDay Demo/devday-24-labs-demo-app/node_modules/sharp: Command failed.
Exit code: 1
Command: (node install/libvips && node install/dll-copy && prebuild-install) || (node install/can-compile && node-gyp rebuild && node install/dll-copy)
Arguments: 
Directory: /Users/thedreamsaver/Downloads/DevDay Demo/devday-24-labs-demo-app/node_modules/sharp
Output:
sharp: Detected globally-installed libvips v8.15.3
sharp: Building from source via node-gyp
gyp info it worked if it ends with ok
gyp info using node-gyp@9.3.1
gyp info using node@18.17.1 | darwin | arm64
gyp info find Python using Python version 3.12.6 found at "/opt/homebrew/opt/python@3.12/bin/python3.12"
gyp info spawn /opt/homebrew/opt/python@3.12/bin/python3.12
gyp info spawn args [
gyp info spawn args   '/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/gyp/gyp_main.py',
gyp info spawn args   'binding.gyp',
gyp info spawn args   '-f',
gyp info spawn args   'make',
gyp info spawn args   '-I',
gyp info spawn args   '/Users/thedreamsaver/Downloads/DevDay Demo/devday-24-labs-demo-app/node_modules/sharp/build/config.gypi',
gyp info spawn args   '-I',
gyp info spawn args   '/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/addon.gypi',
gyp info spawn args   '-I',
gyp info spawn args   '/Users/thedreamsaver/Library/Caches/node-gyp/18.17.1/include/node/common.gypi',
gyp info spawn args   '-Dlibrary=shared_library',
gyp info spawn args   '-Dvisibility=default',
gyp info spawn args   '-Dnode_root_dir=/Users/thedreamsaver/Library/Caches/node-gyp/18.17.1',
gyp info spawn args   '-Dnode_gyp_dir=/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp',
gyp info spawn args   '-Dnode_lib_file=/Users/thedreamsaver/Library/Caches/node-gyp/18.17.1/<(target_arch)/node.lib',
gyp info spawn args   '-Dmodule_root_dir=/Users/thedreamsaver/Downloads/DevDay Demo/devday-24-labs-demo-app/node_modules/sharp',
gyp info spawn args   '-Dnode_engine=v8',
gyp info spawn args   '--depth=.',
gyp info spawn args   '--no-parallel',
gyp info spawn args   '--generator-output',
gyp info spawn args   'build',
gyp info spawn args   '-Goutput_dir=.'
gyp info spawn args ]
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/gyp/gyp_main.py", line 42, in <module>
    import gyp  # noqa: E402
    ^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/gyp/pylib/gyp/__init__.py", line 9, in <module>
    import gyp.input
  File "/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/gyp/pylib/gyp/input.py", line 19, in <module>
    from distutils.version import StrictVersion
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'distutils'
gyp ERR! configure error 
gyp ERR! stack Error: `gyp` failed with exit code: 1
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.onCpExit (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/lib/configure.js:325:16)
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.emit (node:events:514:28)
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess._handle.onexit (node:internal/child_process:291:12)
gyp ERR! System Darwin 23.6.0
gyp ERR! command "/usr/local/bin/node" "/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/bin/node-gyp.js" "rebuild"
gyp ERR! cwd /Users/thedreamsaver/Downloads/DevDay Demo/devday-24-labs-demo-app/node_modules/sharp
gyp ERR! node -v v18.17.1
gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v9.3.1
gyp ERR! not ok

Getting error with Sharp/Libvips when installing node modules in a next application. My node version is v18.17.1

This question is similar to: distutils not found when running npm install. If you believe it’s different, please [edit] the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.
